# Why basic_ifstream show me wrong results?

Tags: c++, file, binary, ifstream

I have a binary file. There are 2288*2288 longitude float values stored in top half section, and the same number of latitude float values occupied the bottom half. I used the following code to load them into a float vector. It can run like a charm, but gave me incorrect results. With regard to my binary file, the float vector should be filled with a total of 2288*2288*2=10469888 elements, but only 159005, all their values are the same 200.0000. Would you please explain what's wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

```
bool LoadData(const char* pszDataFile)
{   
    typedef char_traits<float> traits_type;
    typedef std::codecvt<float, char, mbstate_t> cvt;

    std::basic_ifstream<float, traits_type> input( pszDataFile, std::ios::binary );
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new cvt());
    input.imbue(loc);

    std::vector<float> fvBuffer;    

    // Copies all data into buffer 
    std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<float>(input),          
              std::istreambuf_iterator<float>( ),         
              std::back_inserter(fvBuffer)); 

    long nSzie = fvBuffer.size();  // Wrong vector size (159005)

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should use the `{}` button in the editor to indent your code, not html tags, they're kinda broken.

Comment: What is the definition of `char_traits<float>`? Have you defined it yourself? As far as I know, the standard library haven't defined it.

Comment: char_traits<T> is a templated type, and also the basic_ifstream. I actually use basic_ifstream<float, char_traits<float> > to declare an input file instance instead of its ifstream.

Comment: Surely, it uses char as its default type.

Comment: The standard only mandates specializations of `char_traits<>` for `char` and `wchar_t`; for any other type, **you** must provide a specialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make std::basic_ifstream works, you have to define your trait_type so that it provides everything expected by input stream, and I'm not sure that it will be possible.  That will be far more than just a `codecvt<float, char, mbstate_t>` (which you seem to think is already present while the standard demand only the wchar_t, char and char, char specializations).

If you want a binary input iterator, you'll have to write one yourself to work with basic_ifstream,  something like this (run and give the expected result, but not debugged further):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class BinaryInputIterator
    : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T, std::ptrdiff_t,
                           const T*, const T&>
{
public:
    BinaryInputIterator();
    BinaryInputIterator(std::istream&);
    // Compiler generated version OK:
    // BinaryInputIterator(BinaryInputIterator const& other);
    // BinaryInputIterator& operator=(BinaryInputIterator const& other);
    ~BinaryInputIterator();

    T const& operator*() const;
    T const* operator->() const;
    BinaryInputIterator& operator++();
    BinaryInputIterator operator++(int);

private:
    std::istream* myStream;
    T myValue;

    friend bool operator==
       (BinaryInputIterator const& l, BinaryInputIterator const& r)
    {
        return ((l.myStream == NULL && (r.myStream == NULL || !*r.myStream))
                || (r.myStream == NULL && (l.myStream == NULL || !*l.myStream)));
    }
    friend bool operator!=
       (BinaryInputIterator const& l, BinaryInputIterator const& r)
    {
        return !(l == r);
    }
};

template <typename T>
BinaryInputIterator<T>::BinaryInputIterator()
    : myStream(0)
{}

template <typename T>
BinaryInputIterator<T>::BinaryInputIterator(std::istream& is)
    : myStream(&is)
{
    myStream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myValue), sizeof myValue);
}

template <typename T>
BinaryInputIterator<T>::~BinaryInputIterator()
{}

template <typename T>
T const& BinaryInputIterator<T>::operator*() const
{
    return myValue;
}

template <typename T>
T const* BinaryInputIterator<T>::operator->() const
{
    return &myValue;
}

template <typename T>
BinaryInputIterator<T>& BinaryInputIterator<T>::operator++()
{
    myStream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myValue), sizeof myValue);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
BinaryInputIterator<T> BinaryInputIterator<T>::operator++(int)
{
    BinaryInputIterator result(this);
    ++*this;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
 {
    std::ofstream os("foo.dta");
    std::vector<float> vect1;
    vect1.push_back(4.2);
    vect1.push_back(3.14);
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vect1[0]), sizeof(float)*vect1.size());
 }
 {  
    std::ifstream is("foo.dta");
    std::vector<float> vect2;
    std::copy(BinaryInputIterator<float>(is),
              BinaryInputIterator<float>(),
              std::back_inserter(vect2));
    std::copy(vect2.begin(), vect2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment to my code. (1) I see. The two lines may be specially designed for codep page conversion. If I comment out the two line. The result was the same. But I googled on the net. Someone used for that purpose. It's took me for a long time to troubleshoot this problem. I could not make success.

Comment: (2) istreambuf_iterator is not designed for formatted output. At least I think so.

Comment: The {i,o}stream_iterators are delegating their work to operator{>>,<<} which are doing formatted IO.

Comment: I'd ever used the following code   std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input),          
           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( ),         
           std::back_inserter(cBuffer));

Comment: Use a ifstream, and std::copy(BinaryInputIterator<float>(input), BinaryInputIterator<float>(), std::back_inserter(fVector)).  There are far too many things to define in order to be able to have a std::basic_ifstream<float, traits_type>.

Comment: Dear AProgrammer
Thank you for your hard work. But your code can not compile.

Comment: OK! I made the code to be compiled. I'll have a test, and let you know the result.

Comment: Sir, When use your BinaryInputIterator like this :bool CNOMLonLatLookup::LoadData(const char* pszDataFile)
{   
 ifstream input( pszDataFile, std::ios::binary );
  std::vector<float> fvBuffer;    
    copy(BinaryInputIterator<float>(input), BinaryInputIterator<float>(), std::back_inserter(fvBuffer));

   long nSzie = fvBuffer.size();  

    return true;
}
 It throwed many errors.

Comment: f:\tips\tips\nomlonlatlookup.h(50) : error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\tips\tips\nomlonlatlookup.h(50) : error C2070: ''unknown-type'': illegal sizeof operand
1>e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility(764) : error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'BinaryInputIterator<T>'

Comment: 1>e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility(764) : error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'BinaryInputIterator<T>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>        e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility(2563) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>' being compiled

Comment: @GoldenLee, I've updated my answer with code tested a little more.

Comment: Dear AProgrammer, I appreciate your kind help. Your code works now! BTW, my original code worked too. I made a mistake. See my modified code.

Comment: bool LoadData(const char* pszDataFile)
{ 
    typedef char_traits<float> traits_type;
    typedef std::codecvt<float, char, mbstate_t> cvt;
    
    std::basic_ifstream<float, traits_type> input;
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new cvt());
    input.imbue(loc);
    input.open (pszDataFile, std::ios::binary );

Comment: std::vector<float> fvBuffer;    
    
    // Copies all data into buffer 
    std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<float,traits_type>(input),          
              std::istreambuf_iterator<float, traits_type>( ),         
      std::back_inserter(fvBuffer)); 
     
    // Pipe to console
    std::copy(fvBuffer.begin(), fvBuffer.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>
            std::cout, "\n"));  
}

Answer (score 1):

If you imbue() a file stream after the file is opened the imbue() will silently fail.

You must do the imbue() then open the file:

```
std::basic_ifstream<float, traits_type> input;
std::locale loc(std::locale(), new cvt());
input.imbue(loc);

// Open after the imbue()
input.open( pszDataFile, std::ios::binary );
```

Your second problem is you are confusing the terms binary file:

This code reads a stream of text data (i.e. a text file) using the operator >>

```
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<float>(input),          
          std::istreambuf_iterator<float>( ),         
          std::back_inserter(fvBuffer));
```

The use of `std::ios::binary` when you open the file only affects the how the 'end of line sequence' (EOLS) is generated it has nothing to do with the nature of the file. Though because you specify it the '\n' character is not converted into the EOLS which is useful when you are generating binary files.

So the short answer is you better by reading a text stream from a file.

The reason your vector is shorter than what you expect is because the stream reading encountered an error and as a result stopped responding to read requests.

Additionally I can't get your code to compile.
So you are doing something else non-standard.

Comment: Dear Martin. I agree with the first part of your answer. But as for the second part, std::copy(.... was maily used to read plain text file. My knowledge can'y talk back to your opinion. Please see the link http://d.hatena.ne.jp/y-hamigaki/20091230. At the end of the webpage, the author read a binary file tmp.pcm.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I forgot to tell you. Please add the following header files. #include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <locale>

Comment: @GoldenLee: Very interesting article. Unfortunately I don't read (whatever language that is). I spotted a couple of mistakes in the traits and the code cvt class but basically they are sound. By using a custom code cvt class you are translating the float between an internal to an external format (which seems to be binary).  So I suppose that you could call the file binary, but I would rather call it an encoded text stream because of its use of the stream operators, but that is splitting hairs.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. I finally made it to work. Please see my last 2 comments to Mr. AProgrramer. I missed ", traits_type" part.